# How can I generate a map key for this vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, performance, vector, hashmap, key

I have a function that is looking at a number of elements. Each element is of the form of an 8x1 column vector. Each entry in the vector is an integer less than 1000. Every time I see such a vector, I'd like to add it to a list of "already seen" vectors, after checking to see that the vector is not already on this list. The function will examine on the order of ~100,000 such vectors.

Originally I tried using `ismember(v', M, 'rows')`, but found this to be very slow. Next I tried:

```
found = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'any');
```

Then each time I examine a new vector `v`, compute:

```
key = dot(v, [1000000000000000000000 1000000000000000000 1000000000000000 ...
              1000000000000 1000000000 1000000 1000 1]);
```

Then check `isKey(found, key)`. If the key is not in the container, then `found(key) = 1`.

This seems like a pretty lousy solution, even though it does run considerably faster than `ismember`. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Perhaps it would be better to use `mat2str` to generate the key, rather than this silly dot product?

Comment: Do you have to process them sequentially? You could concatenate all the vectors in to a 100,000-by-8 array z and call unique(z, 'rows', 'first') on it, to identify the distinct values and indexes of the first occurence of each.

Comment: The dot product hash is faster than mat2str, but you have hash collisions due to rounding errors because the hash range falls outside the relative precision of the `double` type. E.g. the hashes for [999 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] and [999 1 1 1 1 1 1 2] through [999 1 1 1 1 1 1 100] will collide. Mat2str based hashes will not have this problem. And mat2str is pretty fast here, ~80 usec for me. Try timing your candidate hash functions with tic/toc, and profile the whole thing. Sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to generate a key/hash in your case would be to just convert the vector of integer values to a character array using [`char`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html). Since your integer values never go above 1000, and `char` can accept numeric values from 0 to 65535 (corresponding to Unicode characters), this will give you a unique 8-character key for every unique 8-by-1 vector. Here's an example:

```
found = containers.Map('KeyType', 'char', 'ValueType', 'any');

v = randi(1000, [8 1]);  % Sample vector
key = char(v);
if ~isKey(found, key)
  found(key) = 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

your idea is good. but you need to find a better hash function. use some standard hash function. 
There is an implementation of 'sha' algorithms you's like to see:

http://www.se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31795-sha-algorithms-160224256384-512

If you find the sha algorithm slow then you can probably resort to some tricks. One that i can think of now is following:

1. take a seed number > 1000 e.g. 1024
2. divide each number in the vector by the seed and store the remainder in a string.
3. concatenate all the remainders which will serve as your 'code' for your vector element. which can be used for comparison when a you see a new element.

this should probably work but you'll have to check.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say, "don't download roll-your-own crypto code from the web". You can call Java's standard `java.security.MessageDigest` class directly from Matlab, using `typecast(v,'int8')` to convert the Matlab `double` array to Java `byte[]`, then dec2hex the answer if you need it in string form. It's likely to be faster and more correct that the fileexchange version.

Comment: calling Java's standard `java.security.MessageDigest` is not likely to be faster at least,  you'll have to do some tweaks for that. For reference you can check the following links:
 http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/281221

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/246361#639453

Comment: There is some overhead in the Java calls, but you only have to pay it a couple times per hash computation. This is outweighed by the fact that the fileexchange function you linked is, like a lot of the roll-your-own crypto code on the web, low quality. In testing, I had to modify it to be usable at all, and a simple java.security.MessageDigest based implementation was 600x faster, doing Eric's 8-long vectors in about .0001 sec vs .6700 sec. "Java in Matlab is slow" is an oversimplification.

Comment: Cryptographic hashes are wholly inappropriate for dictionary keys, because *they are designed to be slow to make brute-force attacks more expensive*.

Comment: @A.K. How does the script you link actually work? I read the documentation for it but can't get it to work, what are the inputs supposed to be? Intuitively, input should be whatever message you have and specification as to which hash function you want to use, but this script has three inputs, and doesn't accept hash(-,SHA256,-) despite saying that SHA256 is a valid input.

Answer (score 0):

Not really into hashing, but still believe to have found the simplest way to solve your problem.

This runs about 10x faster than ismember.

```
any(v(1)==M(1)&v(2)==M(2)&v(3)==M(3)&v(4)==M(4)&v(5)==M(5)&v(6)==M(6)&v(7)==M(7)&v(8)==M(8));
```