# MATLAB containers.Map with tuple as key

Tags: matlab, dictionary

I'd like to make a `containers.Map` object that uses a tuple, such as `[4,1]`, as the key. However, this is not a valid key type. How can I convert this into a valid key type?

My ultimate goal is to have something like a sparse cell array that I can index like a matrix but store arbitrary objects.

Comment: Can't you use a 2D cell array?

Comment: Yes, but I am concerned about the memory usage if the total extent of the cell array is large (thousands on each side)

Comment: If you want something that behaves like a sparse cell array, implement a class that behaves like a sparse cell array, don't abuse `containers.Map`. For example, just have a class that contains a sparse array of indices as one property, a cell array of things as another, and then overload `subsref` on the class so that you get the right thing when you index into it.

Comment: Closely related/possible duplicate: [How can I generate a map key for this vector in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751309/52738)

Comment: The solution I've come up with is to create a 2D [sparse array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) `A` and store values like `A(4,1)=my_val` using tuple key as index; may not be the fastest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received a lot of answers as comments, so for posterity (and my own sanity) I am writing these up as actual answers.

## Tuple to scalar via `sub2ind`

If you are trying to emulate the behavior of a sparse matrix with a known size, then you can convert any valid tuple into a unique linear index using `sub2ind`.

For example, if your hypothetical sparse cell array is to be 1000 x 200 in size, then you can do:

```
sp_cell = containers.Map('KeyType','double', 'ValueType','any');
key_converter = @(i,j) sub2ind([1000,200], i,j);
sp_cell(key_converter(4,1)) = 'foo';
```

## Tuple to string via `mat2str`

Alternatively (and more generally), you can use `mat2str` to convert your tuples into strings, but then you'll lose the checking of array index bounds that `sub2ind` provides:

```
sp_cell = containers.Map('KeyType','char', 'ValueType','any');
key_converter = @(tup) mat2str(tup);
sp_cell(key_converter([4 1])) = 'bar'
```

## Tuple as unicode string

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603623/1877862): if each index is less than or equal to 65535, then you can convert the tuple into a string directly.

```
key_converter = @(tup) char(tup);
```

## Hashing

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751796/1877862): You can hash the tuple into a string.

```
md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('MD5');
key_converter = @(tup) char(md.digest(tup));
```

The downside here is that you can't convert the map key back into a tuple.

## Sparse lookup table

From @SamRobert's comment: you can create a sparse array of indices into a 1-D cell array. Here is a quick-and-dirty mockup of a class:

```
classdef SparseCellArray
    properties (Access=protected)
        lookup
        contents
    end
    methods
        function self = SparseCellArray(m,n)
            % Constructor; takes array dimensions as [#rows, #cols]
            self.lookup = sparse(m,n);
            self.contents = {};
        end
        function B = subsref(self, S)
            % Overload matrix-style indexing
            assert(isscalar(S) && strcmp(S.type,'()'));
            idx = self.lookup(S.subs{1}, S.subs{2});
            assert(idx ~= 0, 'Index not found');
            B = self.contents{idx};
        end
        function newobj = subsasgn(self, S, B)
            % Overload matrix-style indexing 
            assert(isscalar(S) && strcmp(S.type,'()'));
            idx = self.lookup(S.subs{1}, S.subs{2});
            newobj = self;
            if (idx == 0)
                idx = length(self.contents) + 1;
                newobj.lookup(S.subs{1}, S.subs{2}) = idx;
            end
            newobj.contents{idx} = B;
        end
    end
end
```

And the usage is as follows:

```
sp_cell = SparseCellArray(2000,100);
sp_cell(4,1) = 'foo';
```

Downside is that it only accepts 2-D arrays (since `sparse` only produces 2-D arrays). Note also that any of these solutions can be wrapped in a class like this.

Comment: The tone of this answer confuses me, and reads like you forgot to log into your alternate account to post an answer.

Comment: How can I edit this to be less confusing? Also, is it bad etiquette to answer your own question? I didn't know that I needed an alternate account to do this.

Comment: [Self-answers are explicitly encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). The leading question of this answer is a bit strange and makes it sound like you're trying to talk to yourself from an alternate account.