# Matlab hash table with matrix key

Tags: matlab, hash, containers

I would like to construct a hash table in Matlab, the keys of which are matrices of different sizes, and the values of which are also matrices. The `containers.Map` class only allows strings as keys. I can certainly just use a cell for the keys, a cell for the value and match the indices of the two cells. Is there a better way to construct the hash table and the associated hash function?

Comment: Using matrices of different sizes as keys? Interesting! Never seen that before. Just out of curiosity, what is the application?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I have a kind of functional Taylor expansion. The higher order functional derivatives indexed by the larger size matrices recursively depend on the lower order ones indexed by the smaller size matrices. I need to label the computed values with those matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I just played around with `containers.Map` a little, it seems that you can use char arrays of any length as keys.

```
>> a = containers.Map;
>> a(repmat('bla',50,500)) = 1;
>> a(repmat('bla',50,500))
ans =
     1
```

You can also convert any numeric array into a char array as follows:

```
>> x = randn(4)
x =
   -0.7371   -0.0799    0.1129   -1.1667
   -1.7499    0.8985    0.4400   -1.8543
    0.9105    0.1837    0.1017   -1.1407
    0.8671    0.2908    2.7873   -1.0933

>> s = char(typecast(x(:),'uint8')')
s =
    ''uÔ_þç¿¼qÿû¿/å\¬"í?éúè#¿ë?.YðjÛs´¿Ó¶Ó·PÀì?+Ç? Õ9NÒ?Üéñé¼?
     °À9-(Ü?ç¥ìÆº?NsivL@V*aó¨ªò¿{Ò5«ý¿Q8ß:@ò¿í=µU~ñ¿'
```

Or using the full 16-bit Unicode values allowed by `char`:

```
>> s = char(typecast(x(:),'uint16')')
s =
    '疺㓦쁁뿛쓆遫뿅䅀庲뿋ꁰ頳劜㿡礋쮼㿘旈帡਑㿨ﮢ电玼㿼譍৊醪㿳랝趚蠷뿴瞶ꆲ쀂伴愹?㿬ꑨ꬞廆뿽㼝ὧ᛻㾱?ﺳ⩝㾢棑罓턽䀁ᕾ統렆뾱'
```

So putting these together, it is possible to use any array (properly converted to a char array) as key into a hash table:

```
>> a(s) = 5;
>> a(s)
ans =
     5
```

---

And, given the numeric array cast to `char`, it is possible to cast it back to numeric array as well (though the shape of the array will get lost):

```
x = randn(1,20);
s = char(typecast(x,'uint8'));
y = typecast(uint8(s),'double');
assert(isequal(x,y))  % does not throw an error
```

---

There is another alternative. It **is** possible to use keys of type different from a string with `containers.Map`, [as stated in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html#d119e679670). Keys can be either char arrays, or numeric scalars; they cannot be numeric arrays:

```
>> a = containers.Map('KeyType','double','ValueType','double');
>> a(5) = 10;
>> a([5,3]) = 5;
Error using containers.Map/subsasgn
Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.
```

Thus, you could compute a hash value (as a floating-point double value or 64-bit integer value) from your arrays. How to best do this I don't know, maybe the dot product with a set of random values? At [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751309/how-can-i-generate-a-map-key-for-this-vector-in-matlab) there are some suggestions. There are also some functions on the MATLAB File Exchange that would be helpful (e.g. [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25921-getmd5)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not like the transformation into strings of the key matrices because I need to manipulate these matrices. I will check out the two Matlab File Exchange functions you linked to.

Comment: @Hans: Not sure why that matters. You’d have the same problem if you compute a hash value in any other way. The key in the container is not the data.

Comment: I want to perform arithmetic operations on the keys since my computation is recursive.

Comment: @Hans: If you want to look up the matrix/matrices associated to a matrix `M`, you'd do `map(getkey(M))`, but you can then still perform arithmetic with `M`. Maybe my understanding of your problem is not correct, but I don't see the issue. Are you maybe interested in iterating through the map and do operations for each key/value pair? You should probably store them in a cell array then?

Comment: Is your 'M' the key or value? I would like to perform arithmetic operations on the key (matrix). For example, if the key matrix is 'A', I would like to, say, do 'A(1,2)+1'. You said "you should probably store them in a cell array then?" Well, did you read the second last sentence of my question, namely "I can certainly just use a cell for the keys, a cell for the value and match the indices of the two cells."?

Comment: @Hans: [A recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53594913/7328782) brought me back here. I think I understand a bit better what you wanted. Not sure this is still a concern for you. But I wanted to let you know that it is possible to convert the string used as key back to a numeric array without any loss (the recovered array is identical to the original array) except for the matrix shape (since it has to be converted to a vector). I have updated this answer to show this.

Comment: Thank you for revisiting this question. The typecasting function from characters to floating numbers you suggest takes only vectors though rather than a general matrix. As for the hash between a scalar and a matrix, it is easy to construct.  Normalize the range of the matrix to the n-dimensional unit hypercube. If the precision is infinite, then use the continuous space-filling curve to establish the homeomorphism between the cube and the interval $[0,1]$. If the precision is finite, simply concatenate the fixed length decimal parts together to get a single decimal expression.

Comment: The continuous space-filling curve can be constructed using the Cantor function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#Outline_of_the_construction_of_a_space-filling_curve.

Comment: @Hans: How about encoding the matrix shape in the string as well? `char(typecast([size(x)';x(:)],'uint8'))`. The inverse conversion can then reshape the matrix back to its original shape.

Comment: Which inverse conversion are you referring to, typecast()?

Comment: @Hans: Something like `x=typecast(uint8(s),'double'); x=reshape(x(3:end),x(1),x(2));`